# Updating a table which was created by a 'AS select' command

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have created a table using a 'AS SELECT' statement.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
SELECT ... 
from (MANY TABLES) 
WHERE (MANY CONDITIONS);
```

How do I make sure that updates on any of the table columns go onto TEST as well?

Or do I have to use a VIEW? (which I dont want to as there is a need of a trigger to be working on TEST)

Are any other options available other than using a VIEW ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a View.
CREATE TABLE AS SELECT just make a copy of data at the moment of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Look into creating the table test as a materialized view.
Triggers can be placed on these and there are various update options too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database system you could use a [Trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) to insert the values in the other table as well. That's if you need something like near-realtime syncronization. Or you might go for a daily/weekly/... batch synchronization.

As I am not so familiar with Oracle you should look at their documentation for a detailed description.